# Detect mime type of an image via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am detecting images on my webpage with javascript document.images function which returns an rray of images. Is there any way to get the mime type of the image from this since i am not using any extension names on images which are loading?

Comment: Just curious - why do you need that information in javascript?

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan Detecting gifs and replacing them with placeholders comes into mind …

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible, apart from requesting the image again in jQuery and trying to use a MIME type check on the data. (You might be able to send a HEAD request and get whatever Content-type was returned)

Comment: an AJAX HEAD request is the only thing I too can think of.

Answer (score 0):

According with other answers, I got pretty surprised to find out it was *apparently* not possible without requesting the image again. *(??? That seems weird to me but oh well…)*

Another *hacky-but-might-be-enough-for-your-use-case*-solution that comes in my mind would be to:

**Parse the `img.src` in an attempt of guessing the file type.**

- *"Guessing?"* you may ask…
- Yes because the extension might not be included in the `src` or could be misleading.